# Dictionary keys are mistakenly strings not integers

Tags: python, string, dictionary, types, key

I'm importing data from csvs and running into a problem with the data type of my keys. All my data types should be 'ints', but instead the first two keys are 'floats'. I think this is causing problems later in my code where I'm using increments and counters  as keys to pull specific values.

```
# amount of demand node
demand = open('C:/Users/Emma/Documents/2021-2022/Thesis/Data/demand.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
csv_demand = csv.reader(demand)
mydict_demand = {}
for row in csv_demand:
    key_start = row[0:2]
    for index, item in enumerate(row[2:21], 1):
        key = tuple(key_start + [index])
        mydict_demand[key] = item   
#print(mydict_demand)

# amount of supply node
supply = open('C:/Users/Emma/Documents/2021-2022/Thesis/Data/supply.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
csv_supply = csv.reader(supply)
mydict_supply = {}
for row in csv_supply:
    key_start = row[0:2]
    for index, item in enumerate(row[2:21], 1):
        key = tuple(key_start + [index])
        mydict_supply[key] = item   
#print(mydict_supply)

snode = list(mydict_supply.keys()) 
supply = mydict_supply
#snode = tuplelist(snode)

dnode = list(mydict_demand.keys()) 
demand = mydict_demand
#dnode = tuplelist(dnode)
```

I coded it this way on another user's suggestion. In my csv, I want the value in the first two columns to be the key, and then the column number of the following 20 columns to be the final key. For example, if my csv looks like Tester:

```
Tester = [[1, 1, 3, 1, 10, 5, 10],
          [1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 3, 8  ],
          [1, 4, 5, 9, 7, 2, 8  ],
          [2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0  ],
          [2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2  ],
          [2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 4, 4 ],]

I want the associated dictionary to be:
(1, 1, 3, 1) = 1
(1, 1, 3, 2) = 10
(1, 1, 3, 3) = 5
(1, 1, 3, 4) = 10
(1, 2, 3, 1) = 7
(1, 2, 3, 2) = 5
(1, 2, 3, 3) = 3
(1, 2, 3, 4) = 8
(1, 4, 5, 1) = 9
(1, 4, 5, 2) = 7 
... # and so on
```

At the moment, when I output values from existing dictionaries like mydict_supply and mydict_demand, the first two keys are strings.

```
print(mydict_demand['1','15',1])
print(mydict_demand[1,15,1])
343029
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-0ce64f0651a5> in <module>
      1 print(mydict_demand['1','15',1])
----> 2 print(mydict_demand[1,15,1])

KeyError: (1, 15, 1)
```

Comment: The `csv` module reads everything as strings. If you need to convert to int, you have to do that in your code. You could also use pandas instead of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The `csv` module doesn't do any parsing except for splitting the line into a list of fields. It doesn't try to interpret the field values, you have to do that in your code.

```
key_start = tuple(map(int, row[0:2]))
```

It looks like you also want to convert the values, so it should be:

```
mydict_supply[key] = int(item)
```

Comment: I recieved this error when I added the suggestion: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-0327151bc189> in <module>
    104     key_start = tuple(map(int, row[0:2]))
    105     for index, item in enumerate(row[2:21], 1):
--> 106         key = tuple(key_start + [index])
    107         mydict_supply[key] = item
    108 print(mydict_supply)

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple

Comment: I'm not sure how comment notifications work, so I'm tagging you as well. thanks!